# Python Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdfplumber

I have an Excel file and that contains an invoice number and I have a pdf file. If the invoice number in the pdf matches the number in the Excel file, I want to write the number in the B column. In the Excel file the invoice number is written in the A column.

This is my code:

```py
import openpyxl
import pdfplumber

# Load Excel file 

excel_file_path = 'path/to/your/excel/file.xlsx'
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
sheet = workbook.active

# Read invoice numbers from Excel

invoice_numbers_excel = \[row\[0\].value for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True)\]

# Load PDF file

pdf_file_path = 'path/to/your/pdf/file.pdf'
with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file_path) as pdf:
page_text = pdf.pages\[0\].extract_text()
invoice_numbers_pdf = \[num.strip() for num in page_text.split('\\n') if num.strip()\]

# Compare and write matching numbers

for row_idx, invoice_num_excel in enumerate(invoice_numbers_excel, start=2):
if invoice_num_excel in invoice_numbers_pdf:
sheet.cell(row=row_idx, column=2, value=invoice_num_excel)

# Save the modified Excel file

workbook.save('datafile.xlsx')
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? Is there an error message? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: You do not tell us what your problem / question is ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), to help us help you.